# Typing effect for multiple lines

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add typing effect to my paragraph.
I found this nice [link](http://www.paulund.co.uk/create-typing-effect) 
It works nicely for one line text. But what I am trying to reach is a paragraph with multiple lines.

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

this css makes the text into one line, but without that nowrap, the effect looks weird.
Anyone has an idea?
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dd6ht/)
HTML:

```
<div class="css-typing">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.css-typing {
    width: 200px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-animation: type 2s steps(50, end);
    animation: type 5s steps(50, end);
}

@keyframes type {
    from { width: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type {
    from { width: 0; }
}
```

Comment: its simple. you don't type in multiple lines at the same time. you remove the `white-space:nowrap` all the text is not in a single line, so the `typing` effect can't be achieved. so you'll need to increase the width of the `.css-typing` element to a substantial amount in case you are using `white-space:nowrap`. it doesn't look like it has support for typing a new line . try http://jsfiddle.net/Dd6ht/5/

Comment: The approach using CSS animations proposed on the page you linked will not work with multi-line text, since it simply changes the width of the element used to display the text (and this is also why it needs `nowrap`). The JS plugin however seems to just append character by character to the text content element of the element, so it should not have that limitation.

Comment: @CBroe you are right. I probably have to look for other solution. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

this might be what you are looking for

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2JpQ/)

```
var spans = '<span>' + str.split('').join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
$(spans).hide().appendTo('.css-typing').each(function (i) {
    $(this).delay(100 * i).css({
        display: 'inline',
        opacity: 0
    }).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 100);
});
```

play around with the duration settings

Comment: it is a nice idea, but I am avoiding using jQuery only for this effect. But thanks

Comment: what does microsoft use for the animation? https://www.microsoft.com/net

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue finally got it working with pure css
here is the source code for 3 lines but its easy to extend to
as many as you would like. the important lines are adding the animation 
delay, next animation fill mode forward is important because I set opacity
to 0 so line would disappear with out it after each animation is done, finally 
in @keyframes type2 and 3 going from opacity 0 to 1 with 1% at 1 make it look like 
it not fading in. I am no CSS expert but hope this helps someone in the future.

```
.css-typing
{   
    font-family: "Courier";
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 50em;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-animation: type 5s steps(40, end);
    animation: type 5s steps(40, end);
}

.css-typing:nth-child(2)
{
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;    
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation: type 5s steps(40, end);
    animation: type2 5s steps(40, end);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s; 
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.css-typing:nth-child(3){
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation: type 5s steps(40, end);
    animation: type3 5s steps(40, end);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s; 
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

 @keyframes type{
    from { width: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type{
    from { width: 0; }
}

span{
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes type2{
0%{width: 0;}
from {opacity:0;}
1%{opacity:1;}
to{opacity:1;}
100%{opacity:1;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes type2{
0%{width: 0;}
from {opacity:0;}
1%{opacity:1;}
to{opacity:1;}
100%{opacity:1;}
}  
@keyframes type3{
  0%{width: 0;}
  from {opacity:0;}
1%{opacity:1;}
to{opacity:1;}
100%{opacity:1;}

} 
@-webkit-keyframes type3{
  0%{width: 0;}
  from {opacity:0;}
1%{opacity:1;}
to{opacity:1;}
100%{opacity:1;}
}
```

Comment: This is pretty good, especially considering that you say you are not CSS expert! Now, you don't show a demo or HTML, but I'm guessing that one has to pre-determine where the line breaks are in the text, thereby limiting true responsive behavior, right? Still good...I guess this is as far as one could take it with CSS only...

Answer (score 1):

Full CSS Multiple line type effect with a caret and with different delays and speed as example.

Codepen Example: css typing multiple line https://codepen.io/Bojoer/pen/EZYgeO

```
<div class="css-typing">
  <p>
    Typed text 1
  </p>
  <p>
    Typed text 2
  </p>
  <p>
    Typed text 3
  </p>
</div>

<style>
.css-typing p {
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 7.3em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(2) {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(3) {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type 5s steps(40, end);
  animation: type3 5s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes type {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}

span {
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is not multiline.

Comment: Why not multiline? It are 3 lines using paragraph tags so I don't see why it's not multiline? I could have used <br> tags but <p> tags also makes it jump to another line so please elaborate on your comment?

Comment: True dynamic multiline would be based on a container bounding box with a single paragraph that automatically line breaks whilst continuing with the typing animation. Three separate lines from three separate animate functions is **not** dynamic nor true multiline functionality.