# Overflow of text in a div. Not able to put the text in div for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have used typewriter effect for entering some facts in my project. The problem I'm having is that on Desktop it is perfect. But when it comes to the mobile devices the text is clipping. Is there any way to make the rest text appear in next line

I have to use a div for the box and encapsulated the line in it. Kindly help me out.

HTML code

```
<div class="typo" >
    <p class="line-1 anim-typewriter">text
    </p>
</div>
```

The CSS code is

```
.line-1{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;  
    width: 5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    font-size: 120%;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 50em;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
}
```

Comment: add the html code, so we can really reproduce this problem

Comment: Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `white-space: nowrap` in this rule, preferable with a media query, or maybe all together

```
 .line-1{
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;  
     width: 5em;
     margin: 0 auto;
     border-right: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
     font-size: 120%;
     text-align: left;
     /* white-space: nowrap;                removed this */
     overflow: hidden;
     max-width: 50em;
     word-wrap:break-word;
     transform: translateY(-50%); 
 }
```

Sample

```css
.typo {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.line-1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;  
    width: 5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    font-size: 120%;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 50em;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    /*transform: translateY(-50%);    temp. removed */
}

.line-1b {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;  
    width: 5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    font-size: 120%;
    text-align: left;
    /* white-space: nowrap;             */
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 50em;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    /*transform: translateY(-50%);    temp. removed */
}
```

```html
<div class="typo" >
    <p class="line-1 anim-typewriter">text bla bla bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla  bla bla bla  bla bla bla  bla bla    </p>
</div>   

<div class="typo" >
    <p class="line-1b anim-typewriter">text bla bla bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla  bla bla bla  bla bla bla  bla   </p>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

When it comes to *typewriter effects*, they often use `white-space: nowrap` since many being a *1 line effect*, so when screen narrows down one get issues.

Here is a post with a couple of options:

- [typing-effect-for-multiple-lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805189/typing-effect-for-multiple-lines)

Comment: Removing that will make the cursor appear equal to height of div and still the content is going outside

Comment: @KartikeyMishra You obviously have another issue, where the _typewriter effect_ doesn't work properly, still, I added a sample showing that it works by removing `white-space`. For the other issue you need to provide more info

Comment: @KartikeyMishra that's much alike the best answer you gonna get from the code you shared with your question (white-space seen, but nothing from what really happens). If you do not share enough code to fully show/demonstrate your issue, at one point you only get average help or guesses :(

Comment: For reference consider this codepen (http://codepen.io/thiagoteles/full/ogoxLw/). I'm trying to use this, kindly check in mobile view the text is clipping. How to fix this? @LGSon

Comment: @KartikeyMishra You break the text down doing something like this: https://codepen.io/Bojoer/pen/EZYgeO ... or use a small script: http://jsfiddle.net/f2JpQ/

Comment: @KartikeyMishra Updated my answer from where I found the above samples

Comment: Thank You. I really appreciate that you helped me out. You saved my time, keep coding keep helping :)