# Typewriter text in more than one paragraph

Tags: html, css, animation, text

I want my text to be longer, so it will take a few paragraphs, but when I do a `<br>` or start a new `<p>` the text in a lower row starts animating at the same time as the first row. It should be blank until the first row is finished and then start animating. Do you have any suggestions?

```css
body {
  background: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

p {
  color: magenta;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200em;
  animation: type 10s steps(200, end);
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  animation: type2 8s steps(60, end);
}

p a {
  color: lime;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span {
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes type {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  to {
    opacity: .0;
  }
}

 ::selection {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <p>This is an example text with animation. Damn <br> Example <span>|</span></p>
  <br> <br>
  <p> well </p>



</body>
```

Comment: Your `<br>` and subsequent text isn't inside the `<p>` that you're animating.

Comment: That's right, but putting it with the new row inside the <p> doesn't change anything

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22805189.  Seems this effect is rather limited.

Comment: I found this but the text is quite small in the example, you'd have to adjust it https://codepen.io/jeryj/pen/WbPVPO