# How to jum the cursor to next line in this animation?

Tags: html, css

I have made the animation that writes:

```
"[Your Name] blah blah"
```

in typing effect. Now I want the cursor to jump to next line and write:

```
"[Your Father Name] blah blah"
```

I have tried adding `<br>` but it writes both lines at the same time and I want it one after the other.

```css
.typewriter h1 {
  color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
  typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
  blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange; }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter" class="username">
    <h1>
     [Your Name] blah blah
    </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You can either use `animation-delay` in your CSS or use `setTimeout` in JS

Comment: @YoavKadosh animation-delay is no working as it prints the second line and gives the typing effect to only 4-5 letters.

Comment: @noobkid you can try [typedjs](https://mattboldt.com/typed.js/) ?

Comment: i got the answer in another stack overflow post....
[click the link and you will find the whole code(only html and css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805189/typing-effect-for-multiple-lines)

Comment: i found the answer on this post..
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805189/typing-effect-for-multiple-lines)

Comment: I got the answer in another stack overflow post.... [click the link and you will find the whole code(only html and css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805189/typing-effect-for-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 0):

So this is my solution on how somebody could to this:

Basically you can toggle a class, that gives your `<div>` the desired animation effect.

- The first typewrite line is visible, and has a class `first typing`
- The second typewriter line is hidden at first, and its class is just `second` (without `typing`)

I now have a js file that checks every 500ms, if the first line is done typing, by checking

```
if ($('.first').parent().width() - $('.first').innerWidth() <= 10)
```

This means that the width of the child is about (~) the width of the parent. 
(The difference is < 10 px)

As soon as the first line is "done" with typing (e.g. its width is almost the parent divs width). add the class `typing` to the second line that you want to type, so that it triggers the animation in the css because the second line now also has a class `typing`.

You can then also remove the `typing` class from the first line etc... (but make sure the css for `first` stays the same after removing `typing` from the first line or otherwise the look will change)

```js
var checking = 1;

function checkForChanges()
{
console.log($('.first').parent().width() - $('.first').innerWidth());
    if ($('.first').parent().width() - $('.first').innerWidth() <= 10) {
      //div is as big as parent
        $(".second").css("visibility", "visible");
        $(".second").addClass("typing");
        //$(".first").removeClass("typing");
    } else {
      // div is smaller/bigger than parent
    }
    
    setTimeout(checkForChanges, 500);
}

checkForChanges(checking);
```

```css
.typewriter{
  width: 100%;
}

.typing {
  color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
  typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
  blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="typewriter" class="username">
    <h1 class="first typing">
     [Your Name] blah blah
    </h1>
    <h1 class="second" style="visibility: hidden">
    [My Name] blah blah
    </h1>
    
</div>
```

Comment: shouldn't even the cursor go to bottom line?

Comment: as i stated in my answer you could remove the typing class from the first line when done with it. this would remove the "cursor" (wich is actually a border in this example)