# typing effect- css to write complete text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write text as typing but The typing effect is not writing long text completely and text is not moving to second line in order to complete writing text.

Any css approach is welcomed(avoiding use of js or jquery).

```css
    /* Google Fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap');
    
    /* Global */
    html{
      min-height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    body{
      height: calc(100vh - 8em);
      padding: 4em;
      color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; 
      background-color: rgb(25,25,25);  
    }
    .line-1{
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;  
        width: 100%;
        border-right: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
        font-size: 180%;
        text-align: left;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        transform: translateY(-50%);    
    }
    
    /* Animation */
    .anim-typewriter{
      animation: typewriter 4s steps(44) 1s 1 normal both,
                 blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;
    }
    @keyframes typewriter{
      from{width: 0;}
      to{width: 100%;}
    }
    @keyframes blinkTextCursor{
      from{border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);}
      to{border-right-color: transparent;}
    }
```

```html
    <p class="line-1 anim-typewriter">Animation typewriter style using css steps() Animation typewriter style using css steps() Animation typewriter style using css steps() Animation typewriter style using css steps()</p>
```

Comment: The text won't move in the second line because you are making it to show in a single line by `white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Removing this is not solving the problem. What should be done here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typing effect for multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805189/typing-effect-for-multiple-lines)

Comment: Yes it will not fix the problem, but just letting you know why its not coming in the next line, the other option is use multiple `<p>` for each line, add delay in the css, after one line finish, start the second and so on.

Comment: Great Tutorial: https://youtu.be/4Mxv8KcAdLE

Answer (score 0):

you can use this css child statements to break down your paragraph and continue it to next line..

```css
.css-typing p {
  margin-left: -20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  font-family: "monospace";
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(1) {
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(2) {
  width: 400px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(3) {
  width: 400;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type3 2s steps(40, end), blink .2s step-end infinite alternate;
  animation: type3 2s steps(40, end), blink .2s step-end infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(4) {
  width: 400px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type4 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(5) {
  width: 400px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type5 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type2 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
  animation-delay: 8s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing p:nth-child(6) {
  width: 400px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type6 2s steps(40, end);
  animation: type4 2s steps(40, end);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
  animation-delay: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type4 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type4 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type5 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type5 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type6 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type6 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: tranparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="css-typing">
  <p>
    typewriter style
  </p>
  <p>
    Animation typewriter
  </p>
  <p>
    style using css
  </p>
  <p>
    steps() Animationy
  </p>
  <p>
    typewriter style using
  </p>
  <p>
    css steps().
  </p>
</div>
```