# how to do typewriter effect with line break with only css and html?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, webkit-animation

## how to do typewriter effect with line break with only css and html?

im making a personal site and am trying out stuff to make certain elements in which i want on my website
and i was intrigued by css animations
and i wanted to do a typewriter in two lines

but there are three things wrong :

• the text doesnt complete (instead of dylxntn it becomes dylxn and programmer becomes program for some reason)
• the timing isnt right, i cant get the timing right

• the second line deletes then rewrites itself instead of just writing itself 
and these things are the only things i know are wrong, there could be something i didnt know about.

```css
    .css-typing h1{
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      border-right: 4px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
      width: 11ch;
      animation: type 3s steps(11, end);
      -webkit-animation: type 3s steps(11, end);
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }

    @keyframes type{
      0% {
          width: 0ch;
      }
      20% {
          width: 11ch;
      }
    }

    .css-typingtwo h1{
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      border-right: 4px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
      width: 16ch;
      animation: type2 3s steps(16, end);
      -webkit-animation: type2 3s steps(16, end);
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }

    @keyframes type2{
      40% {
          width: 16ch;
      }
      80% {
          width: 1ch;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="black">
        <div class="css-typing">
          <font color="white"><h1>I'M <font color="red">DYLXNTN</font></h1></font>
        </div>
        <div class="css-typingtwo">
          <font color="white"><h1>I'M A PROGRAMMER</h1></font>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typing effect for multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805189/typing-effect-for-multiple-lines)

Comment: ok ill see 
and @Itay i tried that before and tried applying my own way but i couldnt get it to work